# There was an error: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python

on Python 3.7.1, I'm trying to use unpy2exe to decompile a .exe program. Unfortunately, I'm getting this error "There was an error: 'module' object is not callable"

Does anyone know how to fix?

```
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import logging

import unpy2exe


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Extract pyc files from py2exe executable.')
    parser.add_argument('filename', help='The py2exe executable')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-o', '--output-dir', default='.',
        help="Output directory")
    parser.add_argument(
        '-p', '--python-version', default=None,
        help="Python major version for pyc (ie: X.Y)")
    parser.add_argument(
        '-v', '--verbose', help="Verbose output", action="store_true")
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())

    if args.pop('verbose', False):
        logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

    try:
        unpy2exe(**args)
    except Exception as e:
        print('There was an error:', str(e))
```

Comment: You're trying to call `unpy2exe`, which is a module, which apparently is not callable…

Comment: how do i fix it? from unpy2exe import unpy2exe gives me an error.

Comment: Well you can't call `unpy2exe` as a function. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I dont know, I didnt code this. This was the original unpy2exe code. Im trying to decompile a .exe to python.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a function in the `unpy2exe` module you have imported. Use:

```
unpy2exe.unpy2exe(*args)
```

Comment: Im not sure it works. im still getting the same error